# How can I autosave data's from other table

Tags: php

I have a problem please I need help, is there a way that if I click the lock button the student who doesn't exist on the table `vote_logs` will automatic put into the other table which is `unvoted_logs(table)`,. For example in the student table there is an `idno c120-115` and also it was saved in the table `vote_logs` my problem is if the vote is time's up then click the button of lock.php, I want that it will automatic put the student records who did not exist in table `vote_logs` to `unvoted_logs`. Need some help guys

[image: Sample of data structure]

Here is my lock.php:

```
<?php
include '../connection/connect.php';
include '../dbcon.php';


$stat='lock';
$sqla = "UPDATE student SET status=?";

$qa = $db->prepare($sqla);
$qa->execute(array($stat));     

//here is the part where I want to store the student who didn't exist in vote_logs
$stud = mysql_query(" SELECT st.* FROM student st LEFT  JOIN studentvotes sv ON st.idno = sv.idno AND st.syearid = sv.syearid
WHERE sv.idno IS NULL AND st.syearid = '$no' AND user_type='3'") or die(mysql_error());

//should I put insert? don't what's next

Header ('Location:lock_unlock.php');
?>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and could you please try to format your question a bit better? It's really hard to understand what you want ;)

Comment: What would you prefer pure PHP or using a SQL stored procedure?

Comment: if you want to autosave if an action is performed on one table in order to perform an action on another, then consider using a trigger. Seems to be the case here.

Comment: I wnt to choose the php

Comment: Plus, looking at your code, you seem to be mixing MySQL APIs. `mysql_` does not support prepared statements. Making your question that much more unclear.

Comment: What can you suggest sir ,? is there a way to automatically store in the database?

Comment: Trigger => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html - And if you want to use PHP, you'll need to use a cron job and seperate files for your SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the use of triggers is the best solution to your problem. Please read this post.

[Using MySQL triggers to log all table changes to a secondary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779230/using-mysql-triggers-to-log-all-table-changes-to-a-secondary-table)

I'm just putting the link because there are many examples of how to make the Internet the registration logs with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion and this may be the answer. Use

mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3 > mydb_tables.sql

either write that in php or in bash and drop it in crontab folder so it'll automatically backup the table. You can also use `crontab -e` to set the backup interval.